# Building a site with a slideshow. Trying to get the previous and next buttons functioning with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Building a site with a slideshow. Trying to get the previous and next buttons functioning with JS. I would also like to be able to click the circle icons and have it take me to the desired slide in which was clicked. Below I have provided my html and JS.

Here is my html
'''

```
<!--slideshow container-->
                    <div id="slideContainer">
                        <!--full-width images with number-->
                        <div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="slideNumber">1 / 3</div>
                            <img src="images/uber-scuba-gili-TucvB6VLPAU-unsplash.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="slideNumber">2 / 3</div>
                            <img src="images/chrisS-seychelles.jpg">
                        </div><div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="slideNumber">3 / 3</div>
                            <img src="images/danielC-barca.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!--next and previous button-->
                        <a class="previous" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <!--circle indicators-->
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                    </div>
```

'''

here is my not functioning JS (sorry brand new to JS)

'''

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 10000); // Change image every 10 seconds
}

var i = 0,mySlides;

function mySlides(param)
{   
    if (param === 'next')
        {
            i++;
            if(i === slides.length) {i = slides.length - 1}
        }else{
            i--;
            if(i < 0) {i = 0}
        }

    document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides").src = slides[i];
}
```

'''

Comment: Will you have multiple slideshows per page? Or you're just experimenting with JS for training?

Comment: only my homepage will have a slideshow with about 5-6 slides